# Visual Studio Diagnostics session failed to start - What access rights are required to run Visual Studio 2013 Diagnostic

Tags: visual-studio-2013, access-rights

Visual Studio 2013 Diagnostics session failed to start:

[image]

Cannot load collector agent. Access is denied.

I would like to know what access rights are required to run Performance and Diagnostic tool

Comment: I have the same problem, althrough in Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, for me it was due to not being a Local Administrator on my Developer Machine.

If I ran Visual Studio under an Elevated Account that was a Local Admin, (shift + right click > run as...) then the diagnostic session would start.