# Visual Studio Diagnostics session failed to start

Tags: visual-studio, diagnostics

I get this weird error when I start my program in Visual Studio.

[image: Diagnostics session failed to start error message]

I already tried to run as local administrator as suggested in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857580/visual-studio-diagnostics-session-failed-to-start-what-access-rights-are-requi) post. That did not help me (my error is also different from the other poster).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Though it is more a nasty fix than an actual solution, unchecking the option 'Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging' in menu 'Tools' -> 'Options' -> 'Debugging' stopped the error from appearing.